# NginX forward request to multiple endpoint in-order and pass each response as new request to next endpoint

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I try to forward request to multiple server in-order. But, each response from current endpoint become a new request for the next endpoint until it reach the last endpoint. The last endpoint's response would be forwarded to user. The flow could be like this:

[image: nginx pass request flow]

This flow is not actual problem, but a sample or dummy. Yes, this is actually inefficient but my actual problem is logic to implement that way. Each endpoints MAY modify not only the body but also the header. Also, the last server HTTP Status would be returned to user, and when it is 4xx or 5xx, it would block the next forwarding and immediately send the error. But if these impossible, the response header become next request header is optional, and also each server may return `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` or something similar for this chaining request.

I have try manythings and find many implementation, but nothing meets my requirement. Here are my founding:

- Proxy Pass: When I try to do with multiple proxy, NginX not working

```yaml
server {
    listen 80;

    location /eval_type1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:134/compile;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:85/exec;
    }

    location /eval_type2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:134/compile http://localhost:85/exec;
    }
}
```

- Mirror & Pass Proxy: works and send to 2 of endpoints, but chaining not working. It just do send the request to the next server, and simultaniously forward the same request to proxy pass. The response from mirror is ignored.
- Post Action & Pass Proxy: same as Mirror, response from each post action ignored, not chained.
- GoReplay: I would like to use NginX as "I trust how mature and trustworthy NginX is", so forwarded to other proxy is not in my intention.
- Upstream Server: only provide the host address, not the endpoint routes
- Auth Request: This is very close to my actual problem, but instead I would like to chain to more than 2 endpoints with have different use-case.
- NJS, CGI, *similar*: I can implement it to NJS or any CGI which Nginx support, but <s>I believe it would create a new process first</s>. And also, this is not clean. I may write an unsafe script to forward the request. Directive made from NginX or Community is more trustworthy.

For some similar question I have found but no answers or meets my requirements, so I plan to reopen the issue:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/993512/reverse-proxy-forward-to-multiple-servers-sequentially
- https://superuser.com/questions/1436131/nginx-dispatch-a-request-to-multiple-endpoints

For my notes for this question:

- I like to only use NginX without using another proxy such us GoReplay or Apache httpD
- But, if there are add-ons or modules to be implemented directly to NginX, I want to try.
- My qustion only **"how to pass request to multiple endpoint in-order and allow each server to modify the request body"**
- Alternatively, my question is **"how to chain request to multiple endpoint and allow modifying the request"**
- Shortly, **"Pass Request to multiple endpoint as middleware in nginx"**
- The questions above may looks differs, but it is actually the same one question.

So, is this possible? Are there some way?

---

Edit:

- I am not too deep dive through documentation or code about NJS Execution Process. But, I ask ChatGPT whether Nginx create new process of NJS every request and it is single-thread. But it answer no. NJS follow the core principle of Nginx, which is there is master process which runs the scripts in worker process. I am not sure it is right, but it solve half of my problem of NJS.
- I found about NJS and stated here https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/NGINX-Conf-2018-slides_Volyntsev-NGINX-JavaScript.pdf
- Thanks to IVO Gelov. I never tried LUA but it looks promising.

Comment: I believe that you might be able to do this with Lua. This [example](https://onelinerhub.com/nginx-lua/how-to-make-http-request) suggests that you can make HTTP requests from Lua (probably multiple in a row) and finally return what nginX must respond to the browser.

Comment: I never take a look at LUA, but I would give a chance. Furthermore, after looking the documentation, I just hope there is something similar to `proxy_pass` directive and have standard like as using `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` to continue the proxy, which maybe require up to 2-3 directive for every endpoint.

Comment: I don't think this is possible out of the box. Your case requires a scripted sequential recipe - but nginX is not a script runner, middlewares and backends are such.

Comment: Alright, I would give a chance to NJS and Lua.